# One line ls command to display symbolic links

Tags: command-line, unix, symbolic-link, ls

How can I use just one single `ls` command to display all symbolic links in my `/dev` directory?

I know `ls -l` and that's about it.

Answer (score 8):

The normal way to do this would be to use `find`, if it is available. With GNU find (and possibly others), you can do:

```
find /dev -type l -ls
```

where the `-type l` condition says match only symbolic links. This will give you output like (copying just a few lines here):

```
1971    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           10 Mar 25 19:29 /dev/disk/by-uuid/593596f4-a5a1-4e87-b985-b0196c2a067b -> ../../sda3
1952    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           10 Mar 25 19:31 /dev/disk/by-uuid/7db08eaf-1d68-4aa3-a8e0-7e62489efb0f -> ../../sdb1
1933    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           10 Mar 25 19:29 /dev/disk/by-uuid/a2d18bff-a710-43a8-b41a-fb39b814a165 -> ../../sda1
4209    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           10 Mar 26 08:22 /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:12.2-usb-0:3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1 -> ../../sdc1
```

You can replace the `-ls` action with whatever you prefer (`-print` and `-exec` spring to mind as useful).

Other than that, I suppose you could use something like `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id | grep ^l`, but [parsing the output of ls is generally a bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 0):

ls -l  | grep ^l

Generate a full listing, and select.

The other solution offered (find /dev -type l -ls) might be more efficient as it doesn't do the full listing, but it invokes 'ls' multiple times so it maybe less efficient.  I'd bet less efficient, but also 'grep' is VERY useful and everyone should understand 'command | grep XXX".

You can use find and only invoke 'ls' once, but it gets more complicated... using xargs or backticks

```
ls -l `find /dev -type l`
```

or maybe something like

```
find /dev -type l -print0 | xargs -0 -L99 ls -l
```

but it's too ugly for beginners (-L 99 is not ideal, but I don't see how to do all args).

Comment: Another way of running `ls` only once: `find /dev -type l -exec ls -l {} +`.

Comment: `find ... -ls` does not invoke the `ls` binary at all. For proof, try something like `strace find . -ls 2>&1 | grep ls` and notice the fact that there are no `ls` invocations prior to the output being printed. (`strace` prints all system calls made by an application, starting at its own call to execute the given command.) Now, something along the lines of `find ... -exec ls '{}' ';'` (and possibly even with `+`, depending on the number of files involved) is different, but that's not what you are talking about.